# Как выложить код python на веб-сервер?

Tags: python, веб-сервер

Испробовал кучу способов как это сделать, но всегда у меня появлялись какие-либо ошибки: в ubuntu не устанавливается библиотека gensim, в iis на винде была ошибка 500 с fastcgi и тд.

У меня есть код, написанный в pycharm, для связи с веб-сервером я использую flask. В коде никаких ошибок нет, он запускается в pycharm и через insomnia я могу отправлять post запросы и получать ответы только со своего компьютера. Я хочу, чтобы все в локальной сети по ip моего компьютера могли также через insomnia отправлять post запросы.

Какой стек программ мне лучше использовать для этой цели?

Я использовал flask, iis, nginx, apache, windows, ubuntu.

Comment: Вот эти «какие-либо ошибки» нужно изучать и чинить, а не бездумно пробовать все способы подряд.

Answer (score 0):

Обычный стек для python приложений из твоего списка:

- Nginx
- Flask (+ gunicorn)
- Ubuntu

Для доступа из локальной попробуй:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```